# no entiendo que esta mal

Tags: python, python-3.x

esto realizando este ejercicio y no se por que me dice que esta mal, lo probé y me da la respuesta que debe entonces acudo a ustedes para ver en que me equivoque por que por mi mismo no se que esta mal

```
def array(string):
    lista = list()
    resultado=list()
    a=string.split(",")
    for i in a:
        lista.append(i)
    if len(lista)<=2:
        print("None")
    else:
        for i in range(1,len(lista)-1,1):
            resultado.append(lista[i])
        b=""
        for i in resultado:
            b=b+i+" "
        b=b.rstrip()
        print(b)

array('1,2,3,4,5')
```

[image: instrucciones del ejercicio]

[image: error]

Comment: pues simplemente el ejercicio te pide que devuelvas el resultado, no que lo imprimas... lo cual es logico en la mayoria (si no todos) los ejercicios de codewars....

Comment: ya lo solucione pero quede con la duda ya que lo unico que me toco cambiar fue el ultimo print por un return b PERO si en el primer print(print("None")) lo cambio por un return me sale que no lo toma y no se porque(en pycharm si me devulve en consola None o Null) igual muchas gracias jajaja

Answer (score 2):

Cambiando los 2 **print** por **return** una vez identado tu código funciona perfecto.

```
def array(string):
    lista = list()
    resultado=list()
    a = string.split(",")
    for i in a:
        lista.append(i)
    if len(lista) <= 2:
        return None
    else:
        for i in range(1,len(lista)-1,1):
            resultado.append(lista[i])
    b=""
    for i in resultado:
        b=b+i+" "
    b=b.rstrip()
    return b
```

De todas formas estás duplicando algunas lineas, creas listas que no necesitas.

Al ejecutar `a = string.split(",")` ya estás creando una lista llamada 'a' con los datos, no necesitas volver a recorrerla y crear otra lista.

En el momento en que cambies el `print None` por `return None` ya no necesitas `else`

Solo falta crear el **nuevo string** con los datos de la lista.
Para crear una cadena con los datos de la lista de forma más eficiente tienes un método llamado **join**. `cadena = ' '.join(lista)` y para recorrerla puedes utilizar la forma `lista[inicio:fin]`. Recuerda que las listas empiezan con índice **0**, con lo que quedaría:

```
    b = ' '.join(a[1:-1])    #   Crear una cadena desde el segundo dato al penúltimo
```

Observa que el espacio que hay entre las comillas antes del **join** es el separador que colocas entre los valores de la lista.
Ahora tu código quedaría:

```
def array(string):

    #   Crear lista con el string
    a = string.split(",")

    #   Comprobar cantidad de datos
    if len(a) <= 2:  #   Devuelve None si hay menos de 3 datos y deja de ejecutarse esta rutina
        return None
    #   Crear una cadena desde el segundo dato al penúltimo
    b = ' '.join(a[1:-1])

    #   devuelve la cadena
    return b
```

Una vez entendidas estas funciones puedes aprovechar aún más las ventajas de ***python*** y encontrarás respuestas que se parecen a:

```
def array(string):
    return None if len(string.split(',')) < 3 else ' '.join(string.split(',')[1:-1])
```

Comment: gracias! pero si cambio los 2 print por return me sale error en codewars y no se porque en pycharm me retorna lo que debe y si todavia estoy muy mal con python me falta mucho jajaja

Comment: La salida por pantalla nos engaña. Al cambiar el primer print quedaba ```return "None"``` con lo que devuelve un texto, mientras que la kata espera que le envies un dato ```NoneType```. Solo hay que quitar las comillas.